# How to calculate the average in OOP?

Tags: java, average

I know how to calculate the average in procedural programming, except that in OOP I don't see how to make this:

I have 2 objects and I want to calculate the average age:

```
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Player> players = new ArrayList<Player>();

    players.add(new Player("Eric", 31, true));
    players.add(new Player("Juliette", 28, false));
```

In my class Player, I have this

```
public class Player {

  public String name;
  public int age; 
  public boolean sex;

  public Player(String name, int age, boolean sex){
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.sex = sex;
  }
```

In my CalculateAverage() method, I don't see how to make this? I have a problem with my loop..

```
public static void CalculateAverage(List <Player> players){
    int sumAge =  0;

    for(Player player : players){
            
    }
  }
```

Comment: Add up all the values you want to average. Divide the total by the number of values.

Comment: The age of each player can be assessed using `player.age`. Add this inside the `for` loop to find the  `sumAge`: `sumAge += player.age`. All now that is left to do is to divide `sumAge` by the number of player. You should try that on your own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Method 1:**

inside your loop sum all the ages and then divide the sum by total number of ages(`players.size()`)

```
 List<Player> players = new ArrayList<Player>();

    players.add(new Player("Eric", 31, true));
    players.add(new Player("Juliette", 28, false));
    double sum = 0;
    for(Player player : players){
        sum = sum +player.age;
    }
    double average = sum/players.size();
    System.out.println(average);
```

**Method 2:**

make use of Java 8 Streams. Convert your list to a stream(`players.stream()`) then map your age to double(`mapToDouble()`) then call average.

*NB `average()` returns an optional. use get(`optionalAverage.get()`) to get the actual value.

```
 List<Player> players = new ArrayList<Player>();
    players.add(new Player("Eric", 31, true));
    players.add(new Player("Juliette", 28, false));
    final OptionalDouble optionalAverage = players.stream().mapToInt(Player::getAge).average();
    System.out.println(optionalAverage);
```